# How to put ResultSet data in an object without duplications

Tags: java, jdbc

My Requirement is to convert result data into object form as I need to transfer the data on some other page and the result-set is non tranferable. I have a `ResultSet` which returns data in rows like

```
ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(query);
while(resultSet.next()) {
    System.out.println(resultSet.getString(1) + "," + resultSet.getString(2));
}
```

Result:

```
Column1 Column2
100 One
100 Two
100 Three
100 Four
100 Five
100 Six
101 Seven
101 Eight
103 Nine
103 Ten
103 Eleven
```

But I want data in an object in this format:

```
Column1 Column2
100 One
    Two
    Three
    Four
    Five
    Six
101 Seven
    Eight
103 Nine
    Ten
    Eleven
```

This means I want a list/hash map in which column 1 data should be the key and corresponding column 2 data should be in some array/collection object as value, so that I can access all corresponding values by providing a particular key.

Comment: That Kind of Formation shold be done in the presentation layer. Not in db layer

Comment: Try something and let us know how it goes. This is not a free code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity you can use hashmap.

```
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> hashmap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
```

In this manner your first column become key and values in second column become ArrayList  corresponding to the first column for implementation please go through following url

[HashMap(key: String, value: ArrayList) returns an Object instead of ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960807/hashmapkey-string-value-arraylist-returns-an-object-instead-of-arraylist)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you are trying to do, this would be the case:

```
Map<String, List<String>> mappedObjects = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
while (resultSet.next()) {
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
    if (mappedObjects.get(resultSet.getString(1)) != null) {
        values = (List<String>) mappedObjects.get(resultSet.getString(1));
    }
    if (values.size() > 0) {
        values.add(resultSet.getString(2));
    } else {
        values.add(resultSet.getString(2));
    }
    mappedObjects.put(resultSet.getString(1), values);
}
```

Comment: Hey Mark...It worked Perfectly fine..Appreciate the quick solution.Thanks